# Get name attribute of selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I never used name attribute, but in MVC looks like i must.

I have

```
<select name="testname" onChange="Alert()">
<option value="8">Test</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
function Alert(){
alert(this.name);
}
```

Result should be alert("testname")

Its simple, but i never used, and its hard to find on google, since everyone asking about getting value or index :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that due to the way you call `Alert`, `this` refers to `window`, not to the DOM element. You could pass it to the function as argument:

```
<select name="testname" onchange="Alert(this)">
```

and

```
function Alert(element){
    alert(element.name);
}
```

There are better ways to attach event handlers than using HTML attributes. I recommend to read the [various articles about event handling on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

Also make sure you understand [how `this` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Of course you could also write

```
<select name="testname" onchange="alert(this.name)">
```

---

If you are using jQuery, then you should use it to bind the event handler. For example:

```
$('select[name=testname]').change(function() {
    alert(this.name);
});
```

Have a look at a [jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery) and take the time to go through the [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/), it's worth it.

Comment: Oh i forgot to include "this" as parameter. Thx!